# Parse.com query getFirst() exception

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform

What query.getFirst() really returns?

> Retrieves at most one ParseObject that satisfies this query. Uses the
>   network and/or the cache, depending on the cache policy. This mutates
>   the ParseQuery. Returns: A ParseObject obeying the conditions set in
>   this query, or null if none found. Throws: ParseException - Throws a
>   ParseException if no object is found.

First is saying that returns null of the object is not found.
After that it says that there will be an exception of object not found..

What it really does?

Thanks.

Comment: Just ran into the same bug. Documentation and/or behavior should be fixed.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1591888041040923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method throws `ParseException`, tested on Parse-1.7.1 SDK

```
e = {com.parse.ParseException@831697061768}"com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query"
code = 101
cause = {com.parse.ParseException@831697061768}"com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query"
detailMessage = {java.lang.String@831697061808}"no results found for query"
stackState = {int[266]@831697061912}
stackTrace = {java.lang.StackTraceElement[0]@831693444272}
suppressedExceptions = {java.util.Collections$EmptyList@831693442224} size = 0
```

Comment: Work around for me was to catch ParseException and see if e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND